# Where can I find a list of create-react-app options?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I know `create-react-app` can accept the flag[`--typescript`](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-typescript) for creating a project with TypeScript, but I couldn't find the complete options list anywhere.

Is this the only flag it supports for project creation?

Comment: go here and explore : https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/getting-started

Comment: `create-react-app --help`

Comment: @sathishkumar The docs does not answer my question

Comment: @JJJ great! thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Found it thanks to @JJJ

```
npx create-react-app --help
```